# How does Apache felix baseline plugin calculate required version change?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, semantic-versioning, baseline

I added a single method definition in a interface and I am getting a baseline error with a suggestion asking me for a major version change. I want to ask how does it calculate whether a major or minor change is required? adding one line method declaration shouldn't be a major change, right?

Is there a way to tell it to ignore this particular method declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new method in an interface means that none of the current implementors are compatible with this version of the interface. Before they become compatible again they will have to implement the new method, thus the version bump is justified. Don't game around it, combine it with more changes or just accept that the bundle version of volatile bundles increases quicker than your version stamp on the fully packaged software.

There's nothing bad to version bumps